# SQL Identity Insert is not creating Identity columns

Tags: sql-server, data-import, sql-import-wizard

I am importing data into a blank database and for some reason it is not creating identity columns.

I have selected "Enable identity insert"

[image]

But it is not creating the identity column.
This is the original one:

[image]

**id** is an identity column, but in the imported table:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Which hasn't created an identity column.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Identity Insert doesn't mean "create an identity" when you `INSERT`, it means enable [`IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the table while the `INSERT` is being performed. if you don't have an `IDENTITY` on the table, then the setting means nothing. Normally, you cannot insert a value into a column that has the `IDENTITY` property. Enabling `IDENTITY_INSERT` on the table, however, allows you to do so.

Comment: The little key icon (the only visible difference, from your pictures) means "primary key". That's not the same thing as being an "identity" column. They are two separate concepts (although often used in conjunction). You might want to clarify your understanding of SQL server terminology and concepts so you are clearer about what is happening and what your choices mean. P.s. a sample CREATE TABLE statement would actually be clearer for us than a picture from SSMS. SSMS can generate the statements for you. Then we know exactly how the table is set up in both databases

Comment: OK, the image might be wrong, but the data is still the same. I will edit the post and put better images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. It right clicked the original database and clicked "Tasks > Generate Scripts" to a new query window. Then I used the **Object Explorer** (F7) on the target database and deleted all the tables. I made sure the scripts I created in the last step were targeting the new database and then I ran them.

Once this was done, I was able to use the import wizard and check the "Enable identity insert".

This worked.

Comment: good plan, I forgot this is a blank DB so no harm in generating it all again with the identity inserts :)

Answer (score 1):

simple. Right click the table, and go to design in SSMS, highlight the primary key.

Check that Identity Specification has the following values.

- Identity Specification = Yes
- (Is Identity) = Yes
- Identity Increment = 1
- Identity Seed = 1

Comment: Sounds great, there are 300+ tables. I don't really want to do that

Answer (score 0):

**may it help**

```
create table YourTableName
(
ID int identity(1,1),
contact_ID int,
ipaddress varchar (50),
task varchar (50)
)
```

And if you want to insert value in  identity column you need to write something like this EXAMPLE :

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTableName ON

INSERT into YourTableName(TheIdentity, TheValue)
VALUES (1, 'First Row')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTableName OFF
```

as you say you have 300+ tables

Go to your column property :

In identity Specification section change  IsIdentity No to Yes 
(By default identity Specification will be NO change to Yes)
Identity Increment 1

Comment: I can't do it like this, there are over 300+ tables